# Cannot raw print to RDP redirected printer

Tags: c#, .net, rdp

So I have to RDP into my dev environment. From there, I've been trying to send a file to a Zebra label printer in RAW print mode. Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389664/print-labels-via-a-redirected-printer), the printer doesn't seem to receive anything. I'm using the same c# example code as a proof of concept. That leas to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2827141/writeprinter-with-raw-data-fails-to-print-with-ts-easy-print), but this is already disabled in my group policies.

I am guessing I am just out of luck and have to copy to local as development occurs, but I was hoping not to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect driver simply doesn't support it.

You can work around it by sharing the printer from your local an adding it that way. Then you can raw print to it.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem on a Windows 2016 Server.

We solved it by changing the value of "Use Remote Desktop Easy printer driver first" in the Group Policy from "Not configured" to "Disabled".

This key is in the folder "Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Printer Redirection configurations".

I'm not sure if on the Computer or User configuration, or on both.